# Отображение анимации изображений на главном экране

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui, анимация, qpainterpath

Хочу создать программу, которая будет рисовать некоторые изображения на главном экране.

То есть, я имею ввиду, чтобы картинки были отображены не в каком-либо отдельном окне, а именно на главном экране **`поверх всех окон`**.

Также чтобы изображения НЕ были статичными, то есть придерживались некоторой логике и меняли свою позицию и, возможно, были бы анимированными.

Подскажите, как я могу это сделать?

Comment: ось какая ? 'главный экран' это где ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Прежде чем запустить мой пример, убедитесь, что вы установили `PyQt5`

```
pip install PyQt5
pip install pyqt5-tools
```

PyQt — реализация фреймворка Qt для языка Python.

**main.py**

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QFrame, QApplication, QDesktopWidget
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPainterPath, QRegion
from win32api import GetKeyState
from random import randint, choice


class Ball(QFrame): 
    def __init__(self):
        QFrame.__init__(self, None, 
        Qt.FramelessWindowHint | Qt.MSWindowsFixedSizeDialogHint | Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint)
        # Qt.MSWindowsFixedSizeDialogHint - Придает окну тонкую границу диалога в Windows. 
        # Этот стиль традиционно используется для диалогов фиксированного размера.
        
        self._R = randint(50, 200)
        self._path = QPainterPath()
        self.DC = QDesktopWidget()
        self._x = choice([1, -1]) * choice([1, 1.3, 1.2, 1.5, 1.6])
        self._y = choice([1, -1]) * choice([1, 1.3, 1.2, 1.5, 1.6])
        
        self.set_ui()
        self.show()
        
    def set_ui(self):
        self.resize(self._R, self._R)
        
        # --- выбор цвета шаров
        self.setWindowOpacity(0.9)
        _Colors = ['#007bff', '#6610f2', '#6f42c1', '#e83e8c', '#dc3545', 
                   '#fd7e14', '#ffc107', '#28a745', '#20c997', '#17a2b8',
                   '#f00', '#0f0', '#00f', '#ff0', '#0ff', '#f0f', ]
        FluentColors = [
            '#FFB900', '#E74856', '#0078D7', '#0099BC',
            '#7A7574', '#767676', '#FF8C00', '#E81123',
            '#0063B1', '#2D7D9A', '#5D5A58', '#4C4A48',
            '#F7630C', '#EA005E', '#8E8CD8', '#00B7C3',
            '#68768A', '#69797E', '#CA5010', '#C30052',
            '#6B69D6', '#038387', '#515C6B', '#4A5459',
            '#DA3B01', '#E3008C', '#8764B8', '#00B294',
            '#567C73', '#647C64', '#EF6950', '#BF0077',
            '#744DA9', '#018574', '#486860', '#525E54',
            '#D13438', '#C239B3', '#B146C2', '#00CC6A',
            '#498205', '#847545', '#FF4343', '#9A0089',
            '#881798', '#10893E', '#107C10', '#7E735F',
        ]
        SocialColors = [
            '#3B5999', '#0084FF', '#55ACEE', '#0077B5',
            '#00AFF0', '#007EE5', '#21759B', '#1AB7EA',
            '#0077B5', '#4C75A3', '#34465D', '#410093',
            '#DD4B39', '#BD081C', '#CD201F', '#EB4924',
            '#FF5700', '#B92B27', '#AF0606', '#DF2029',
            '#DA552F', '#FF6600', '#FF3300', '#F57D00',
            '#25D366', '#09B83E', '#00C300', '#02B875',
            '#00B489', '#3AAF85', '#E4405F', '#EA4C89',
            '#FF0084', '#F94877', '#131418', '#FFFC00',
        ]
        MetroColors = [
            '#A4C400', '#60A917', '#008A00', '#00ABA9',
            '#1BA1E2', '#0050EF', '#6A00FF', '#AA00FF',
            '#F472D0', '#D80073', '#A20025', '#E51400',
            '#FA6800', '#F0A30A', '#E3C800', '#825A2C',
            '#6D8764', '#647687', '#76608A', '#A0522D',
        ]
        
        _color = choice(_Colors)          

        self.setStyleSheet("background-color: {}".format(_color))   
        
        self._path.addRoundedRect(0, 0, self.width(), self.height(), self.width()/2, self.height()/2)
        self.setMask(QRegion(self._path.toFillPolygon().toPolygon()))
        
        # startTimer - Запускает таймер и возвращает идентификатор таймера 
        # или возвращает ноль, если не удалось запустить таймер
        interval = choice([30, 25, 20, 15, 10, 5, 1])
        timerId = self.startTimer(interval)

    def timerEvent(self, t):
        if self.pos().x() >= self.DC.width() - self.width() or self.x() <= 0:
            self._x *= -1
        if self.pos().y() >= self.DC.height() - self.height() or self.y() <= 0:
            self._y *= -1            
        
        self.move(self.pos().x() + self._x, self.pos().y() + self._y,)
        
        if GetKeyState(0x01) < -1:
            sys.exit()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    
    for i in range(12):
        exec('B{} = Ball()'.format((i)))
        
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]